# Insert a php string as multiple rows on MySQL table

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a table with more than 750 rows of data that I paste on a textarea and get as a single string variable, then I pass the data as just one string thru an ajax and I want to insert it on my database in just one INSER INTO line

```
 if(isset($_POST['data'])){
            $data = mysqli_real_escape_string($conexion,$_POST['data']); // get the string of data
    
    // on the next two lines I try to give the format like if it were multiple rows of data to insert
            $data = str_replace("\t", "','", $data); 
            $data = str_replace("\n", "')('", $data);
// at this point $data = data1','data2','data3','data4','data5','data6')
//                       ('data1','data2','data3','data4','data5','data6')
//                       .
//                       .
//                       .
//                       .
//                       ('data1','data2','data3','data4','data5','data6
    $sql = "INSERT INTO table(col1, col2, col3, col4, col5, col5, col6) VALUES ('$data')";
    $result = mysqli_query($conexion,$sql);
```

Is there a way to make this work, I was able to insert the data on the database one value at a time, but is taking to long
Any ideas?

Comment: In what way is this not working? Please provide sample input data and an explanation of how your code is not working.

Comment: Its not doing anything, not even it shows an error message,  I'm guessing is not taking the string as the correct text format or something like that

Comment: You need commas between the sets of values

Comment: ? But you already `have a table`!?!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Multiple rows statement format:

```
INSERT INTO table_name (column_list)
VALUES
    (value_list_1),
    (value_list_2),
    ...
    (value_list_n);
```

You're using newlines to determine when there should be enclosing parenthesis for the record data. Separate it with a comma, per the format above.

```
$data = str_replace("\n", "'),('", $data);
```

Since your $data now consists of many records, each one inside enclosing parenthesis and separated by commas, you don't need to repeat the enclosing parenthesis when you construct your SQL query.

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO table(col1, col2, col3, col4, col5, col5, col6) VALUES $data";
```

My preferred method to debug would be to print out the $sql statement. Then copy it and run it directly against your database to see what errors it throws.

Comment: Thanks Joe Ward, your debug method advice was the key to solve this issue